# How do I update an existing database in BigQuery with a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I want to be able to upload new records into a BigQuery table from Google Sheets. I know how to attach them through Connected Sheets, and have the table mirror the Sheet, however I don't want it to mirror the sheet exactly, I want to be able to upload the sheet into the BigQuery table, and then clear the sheet without it deleting the table. Is there a way to do that through Connected Sheets, or do I need a script to do that.

Thanks.

Everything I find on the topic only shows how to make a table from scratch in BigQuery, and have it mirroring a Google Sheet. This doesn't fit my application because my sheet will get too big if I keep all the records around , too quickly. I want to be able upload the records on a sheet into a database, then clear the sheet without it affecting the database.

Comment: One thought is that you temporarily mirror the sheet as a table, run a SQL to insert the data from this temp table to your target table , or use a scheduled query to do this automatically. Once the data is imported you can delete the entries in the temp mirror with no impact to the target bq table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep everything in BigQuery, and you want to work with exactly one Sheet, I think a saved query using the BigQuery DML (data manipulation language) would be the way to go.

Let's imagine that you have a Google Sheet that you've added to BigQuery as an external table called `my_gsheet` in a dataset called `external`. For the sake of argument let's say it has three columns, `id`, `name`, and `created_at`.

We are going to use an [insert select statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert_select_statement) to append this to a table called `all_records` in a dataset called `big_data`, like this:

```sql
 INSERT
     big_data.all_records
    (id, name, created_at)
 SELECT
     id, name, created_at
   FROM
     external.my_gsheet
```

Now you can save this query and run it whenever you want to bring the latest spreadsheet-based data into your warehouse table.

The table `big_data.all_records` should be created by you in advance; if it's going to be very large you should probably think about making it a partitioned table, and if it's going to be queried a lot you may want to cluster certain columns too.

You could even schedule the query to be run regularly, although beware: if you run the query above multiple times, duplicate rows will be created. If you have a unique identifier (e.g. the `id` column for my record), [this can be avoided](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_examples) with a `MERGE`:

```sql
  MERGE INTO
          big_data.all_records AS target
       USING
          external.my_gsheet AS sheet
          ON
          target.id = sheet.id
        WHEN
 NOT MATCHED
        THEN
        INSERT (id, name, created_at)
         VALUES(id, name, created_at)
```

This query, unlike the previous one, will only insert rows if they have an `id` that doesn't already exist in the table. If the `id` *does* exist, it will do nothing (you could add a `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` clause if you want the ability to overwrite instead).